# Python memoryleak when using numpyarray in classes

Tags: python, numpy, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I'm writing a python-library/package for controlling an oscilloscope. One of the function downloads the traces from the oscilloscope. The data is sent in binary and converted by numpy into a float. In an test_script it will be used in an (almost) infinity loop to save the recorded data(ends when no space is left on the device). But before it can run out of space, the python script runs out of memory.

Here is a broke down version of my library, which suffers the same problem of hoarding memory without releasing it, even though being told to free it:

```
import time
import gc
import numpy
from pympler import muppy, summary

class Measurement:

    data = None

    def __del__(self):
        del self.data
        print("Deleting Measurement")

class Oscilloscope:

    def GetData(self):
        # Simulating the acquiration of the data by reading it in by a file
        p = open(r"rawdata.bin",mode="rb")
        rawdata = p.read()
        mes = Measurement()
        mes.data = numpy.array(numpy.frombuffer(bytes(rawdata), dtype='B'), dtype=float)
        p.close()
        return mes

    def __del__(self):
        print("Deleting Oscilloscope")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    myosci = Oscilloscope()
    for i in range(0,10):
        var = myosci.GetData()
        data = var.data

        # In the real script something will be done with the data
        print("Saving and evaluating Traces")
        time.sleep(0.5)

        del var
        gc.collect()
        print("Collected everything")
        # Show MemoryUsage
        all_objects = muppy.get_objects()
        sum1 = summary.summarize(all_objects)
        # Prints out a summary of the large objects
        summary.print_(sum1)
    print("Done")
```

When executed the output looks like this:

```
Saving and evaluating Traces
Deleting Measurement
Collected everything
                       types |   # objects |   total size
============================ | =========== | ============
               numpy.ndarray |          40 |      9.16 MB
                         str |       18144 |      3.39 MB
                        dict |        4685 |      2.21 MB
                        code |        6556 |    925.30 KB
                        type |        1060 |    868.78 KB
                       tuple |        4209 |    272.90 KB
          wrapper_descriptor |        2209 |    172.58 KB
                         set |         139 |    131.41 KB
                     weakref |        1339 |    104.61 KB
           method_descriptor |        1402 |     98.58 KB
                        list |         396 |     88.62 KB
  builtin_function_or_method |        1165 |     81.91 KB
                 abc.ABCMeta |          84 |     81.50 KB
           getset_descriptor |        1050 |     73.83 KB
                         int |        1994 |     60.12 KB
Saving and evaluating Traces
Deleting Measurement
Collected everything
                       types |   # objects |   total size
============================ | =========== | ============
               numpy.ndarray |          41 |     18.31 MB
                         str |       22639 |      3.70 MB
                        dict |        4685 |      2.21 MB
                        list |        4895 |    959.05 KB
                        code |        6556 |    925.30 KB
                        type |        1060 |    868.78 KB
                       tuple |        4212 |    273.09 KB
          wrapper_descriptor |        2209 |    172.58 KB
                         set |         139 |    131.41 KB
                     weakref |        1339 |    104.61 KB
           method_descriptor |        1402 |     98.58 KB
                         int |        2940 |     85.98 KB
  builtin_function_or_method |        1165 |     81.91 KB
                 abc.ABCMeta |          84 |     81.50 KB
           getset_descriptor |        1050 |     73.83 KB
Saving and evaluating Traces
Deleting Measurement
Collected everything
                       types |   # objects |   total size
============================ | =========== | ============
               numpy.ndarray |          42 |     27.47 MB
                         str |       27134 |      4.00 MB
                        dict |        4685 |      2.21 MB
                        list |        9392 |      1.90 MB
                        code |        6556 |    925.30 KB
                        type |        1060 |    868.78 KB
                       tuple |        4212 |    273.09 KB
          wrapper_descriptor |        2209 |    172.58 KB
                         set |         139 |    131.41 KB
                         int |        3879 |    111.66 KB
                     weakref |        1339 |    104.61 KB
           method_descriptor |        1402 |     98.58 KB
  builtin_function_or_method |        1165 |     81.91 KB
                 abc.ABCMeta |          84 |     81.50 KB
           getset_descriptor |        1050 |     73.83 KB
Saving and evaluating Traces
Deleting Measurement
Collected everything
                       types |   # objects |   total size
============================ | =========== | ============
               numpy.ndarray |          43 |     36.63 MB
                         str |       31629 |      4.31 MB
                        list |       13889 |      2.94 MB
                        dict |        4685 |      2.21 MB
                        code |        6556 |    925.30 KB
                        type |        1060 |    868.78 KB
                       tuple |        4212 |    273.09 KB
          wrapper_descriptor |        2209 |    172.58 KB
                         int |        4818 |    137.34 KB
                         set |         139 |    131.41 KB
                     weakref |        1339 |    104.61 KB
           method_descriptor |        1402 |     98.58 KB
  builtin_function_or_method |        1165 |     81.91 KB
                 abc.ABCMeta |          84 |     81.50 KB
           getset_descriptor |        1050 |     73.83 KB
Saving and evaluating Traces
Deleting Measurement
Collected everything
                       types |   # objects |   total size
============================ | =========== | ============
               numpy.ndarray |          44 |     45.78 MB
                         str |       36124 |      4.62 MB
                        list |       18386 |      4.05 MB
                        dict |        4685 |      2.21 MB
                        code |        6556 |    925.30 KB
                        type |        1060 |    868.78 KB
                       tuple |        4212 |    273.09 KB
          wrapper_descriptor |        2209 |    172.58 KB
                         int |        5757 |    163.01 KB
                         set |         139 |    131.41 KB
                     weakref |        1339 |    104.61 KB
           method_descriptor |        1402 |     98.58 KB
  builtin_function_or_method |        1165 |     81.91 KB
                 abc.ABCMeta |          84 |     81.50 KB
           getset_descriptor |        1050 |     73.83 KB
Saving and evaluating Traces
Deleting Measurement
Collected everything
                       types |   # objects |   total size
============================ | =========== | ============
               numpy.ndarray |          45 |     54.94 MB
                        list |       22883 |      5.25 MB
                         str |       40619 |      4.92 MB
                        dict |        4685 |      2.21 MB
                        code |        6556 |    925.30 KB
                        type |        1060 |    868.78 KB
                       tuple |        4212 |    273.09 KB
                         int |        6696 |    188.69 KB
          wrapper_descriptor |        2209 |    172.58 KB
                         set |         139 |    131.41 KB
                     weakref |        1339 |    104.61 KB
           method_descriptor |        1402 |     98.58 KB
  builtin_function_or_method |        1165 |     81.91 KB
                 abc.ABCMeta |          84 |     81.50 KB
           getset_descriptor |        1050 |     73.83 KB
Saving and evaluating Traces
Deleting Measurement
Collected everything
                       types |   # objects |   total size
============================ | =========== | ============
               numpy.ndarray |          46 |     64.09 MB
                        list |       27380 |      6.55 MB
                         str |       45114 |      5.23 MB
                        dict |        4685 |      2.21 MB
                        code |        6556 |    925.30 KB
                        type |        1060 |    868.78 KB
                       tuple |        4212 |    273.09 KB
                         int |        7635 |    214.36 KB
          wrapper_descriptor |        2209 |    172.58 KB
                         set |         139 |    131.41 KB
                     weakref |        1339 |    104.61 KB
           method_descriptor |        1402 |     98.58 KB
  builtin_function_or_method |        1165 |     81.91 KB
                 abc.ABCMeta |          84 |     81.50 KB
           getset_descriptor |        1050 |     73.83 KB
Saving and evaluating Traces
Deleting Measurement
Collected everything
                       types |   # objects |   total size
============================ | =========== | ============
               numpy.ndarray |          47 |     73.25 MB
                        list |       31877 |      7.85 MB
                         str |       49609 |      5.54 MB
                        dict |        4685 |      2.21 MB
                        code |        6556 |    925.30 KB
                        type |        1060 |    868.78 KB
                       tuple |        4212 |    273.09 KB
                         int |        8574 |    240.04 KB
          wrapper_descriptor |        2209 |    172.58 KB
                         set |         139 |    131.41 KB
                     weakref |        1339 |    104.61 KB
           method_descriptor |        1402 |     98.58 KB
  builtin_function_or_method |        1165 |     81.91 KB
                 abc.ABCMeta |          84 |     81.50 KB
           getset_descriptor |        1050 |     73.83 KB
Saving and evaluating Traces
Deleting Measurement
Collected everything
                       types |   # objects |   total size
============================ | =========== | ============
               numpy.ndarray |          48 |     82.40 MB
                        list |       36374 |      9.26 MB
                         str |       54104 |      5.84 MB
                        dict |        4685 |      2.21 MB
                        code |        6556 |    925.30 KB
                        type |        1060 |    868.78 KB
                       tuple |        4212 |    273.09 KB
                         int |        9513 |    265.71 KB
          wrapper_descriptor |        2209 |    172.58 KB
                         set |         139 |    131.41 KB
                     weakref |        1339 |    104.61 KB
           method_descriptor |        1402 |     98.58 KB
  builtin_function_or_method |        1165 |     81.91 KB
                 abc.ABCMeta |          84 |     81.50 KB
           getset_descriptor |        1050 |     73.83 KB
Saving and evaluating Traces
Deleting Measurement
Collected everything
                       types |   # objects |   total size
============================ | =========== | ============
               numpy.ndarray |          49 |     91.56 MB
                        list |       40871 |     10.79 MB
                         str |       58599 |      6.15 MB
                        dict |        4685 |      2.21 MB
                        code |        6556 |    925.30 KB
                        type |        1060 |    868.78 KB
                         int |       10452 |    291.39 KB
                       tuple |        4212 |    273.09 KB
          wrapper_descriptor |        2209 |    172.58 KB
                         set |         139 |    131.41 KB
                     weakref |        1339 |    104.61 KB
           method_descriptor |        1402 |     98.58 KB
  builtin_function_or_method |        1165 |     81.91 KB
                 abc.ABCMeta |          84 |     81.50 KB
           getset_descriptor |        1050 |     73.83 KB
Done
Deleting Oscilloscope

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The memory is hoarded even though the numpyarrays receive a delete command and the garbage collector gets triggered. In the real script the memory-usage jumps with every step by around 150 mB. The Raspberry Pi which is running my library gets out of memory pretty quick.

If you want to test it yourself, here is the rawdata.bin file used:
https://mega.nz/#!ps4ACAJD!0cqTJJmMU5RjSx5BqggM1afz47PqcR67hzKKnI8LgTs

Comment: If this is a genuine bug with NumPy, have you considered contacting the developers/maintainers?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why this memory is leaking, but I found you can clear it up by adding in a

```
del var
```

where you currently have

```
del data
```

I'll update this if I work out what's actually going on here, its clearly something to do with the lifetime of (multiple copies of) `data`. But this should get you up and running.

(fwiw you can simplify the test case by doing something like `mes.data = numpy.zeros((100,100))` and it still leaks)